# How to create a SQLite Timestamp value in PHP

Tags: php, sqlite, timestamp

I want to generate a timestamp in PHP and then store that value in SQLite.

Here is the code:

> $created_date = date("YYYY-MM-DD
>   HH:MM:SS",time());

Here is what gets stored in the DB (which looks wrong):
11/21/0020 12:39:49 PM

How should I change my code to store the current date/time properly in SQLite

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Why not just update your SQLite query to use `date('now')`? [reference](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_datefunc.html)

But, within PHP you should be able to use

```
$created_date = date('Y-m-d H:i:s');
```

Comment: previously: date_default_timezone_set("UTC");
because SQLite stores dates w/o timezone delta (also "Z" or +00, or the UTC zone). Wich is the right approach.

Answer (score 2):

I just implemented this for my own project..

My solution was to use the UTC time format [officially specified for the web: RFC3339](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3339).
You can use any of the following [PHP time format constants](http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.datetime.php#datetime.constants.types):

- `DATE_RFC3339`
- `DATE_W3C`
- `DATE_ATOM`

**Example:**

```
$sqlite_timestamp = date(DATE_RFC3339);
echo "My SQLite timestamp = ".$sqlite_timestamp;
```

The best part is the alphanumeric order corresponds to the date order, so you can use `ORDER BY` SQL statements on the date fields!

Answer (score 0):

How do you check what the stored value is? Also, what is the datatype of the column in the database? Are you aware that [SQLite is typeless](http://www.sqlite.org/datatypes.html), so all values are being stored as strings or integers?

Answer (score 0):

```
  $created_date = date('Y-m-d H:i:s');
  echo $created_date ."<br />\n";

  $created_date = date('l, F jS, Y - g:ia');
  echo $created_date ."<br />\n";

  $created_date = date('n/j/y H:i:s');
  echo $created_date ."<br />\n";

  $created_date = date('r'); // RFC 2822 formatted date
  echo $created_date ."<br />\n";

  $created_date = date('c'); // ISO-8601 formatted date
  echo $created_date ."<br />\n";
```

Output could be:

```
2011-04-01 19:33:40
Friday, April 1st, 2011 - 7:33pm
4/1/11 19:33:40
Fri, 01 Apr 2011 19:33:40 +0200
2011-04-01T19:33:40+02:00
```

Be aware that [date()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.date.php) function depends of default timezone set in PHP config. You can always test it using `echo date_default_timezone_get();` or set it by `date_default_timezone_set('TIMEZONE_IDENTIFIER');` where TIMEZONE_IDENTIFIER is one from [the list of supported timezones](http://php.net/manual/en/timezones.php).

Answer (score 0):

```php
$db = new PDO('sqlite:database.db', null, null, [
    PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE => PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION,
    PDO::ATTR_DEFAULT_FETCH_MODE => PDO::FETCH_ASSOC,
    PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES => false,
]);

$sql = <<<'SQL'
INSERT INTO stats
(timestamp, ip)
VALUES (datetime('now'), :ip)
SQL;

$query = $db->prepare($sql);
$query->execute([
    ':ip' => $ip,
]);
```